# Placing of subfigures with different widths

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=175px, width=200px]{dummy.png}
    \caption{left}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=175px, width=150px]{dummy.png}
    \caption{right}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and a picture:

[image: a busy cat]

How can I arrange the subfigures so that the space between the right fig and the right border equals the space between the left fig and the left border? I marked the space with red lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\subcaptionbox`, so you don't have to guess.

In the example I added the width, but probably your code will just set the height. Don't use `px` units, because the size of 1px is not predetermined.

Instead of `\hfil` between the images you can use `\hspace{<length>}` (don't forget a `%` if it comes last in a line).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subcaptionbox{left\label{sub-left}}{%
  \includegraphics[height=175bp,width=.6\textwidth]{example-image}%
}\hfil
\subcaptionbox{right\label{sub-right}}{%
  \includegraphics[height=175bp,width=.2\textwidth]{example-image}%
}

\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can set the widths of the two `subfigure` environments directly to `200px` and `150px`, respectively. Next, set the widths of both graphs to `\linewidth`. Finally, insert `\hspace*{\fill}` to the left of the left-hand subfigure, between the subfigures, and to the right of the right-hand subfigure.

If you want a *fixed amount* of space between the subfigures of, say, 1 cm instead of `\fill`, simply replace the middle `\hspace*{\fill}` instruction with `\hspace{1cm}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{200bp}
    \includegraphics[height=175bp, width=\linewidth]{dummy.png}
    \caption{left}
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{150bp}
    \includegraphics[height=175bp, width=\linewidth]{dummy.png}
    \caption{right}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}

\caption{Two subfigures placed side by side}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unit `px`? That's really wrong! Yes, it's used by the OP, but we should know better. The unit `px` *can* be used in `pdftex`, but its value is not fixed (default is 1bp, but one can't count on it).

Comment: @egreg - I've updated the code and replaced `px` with `bp` -- just to play it safe. :-)

Comment: @Mico - Thank you :) It works, but I will be using the other answer, as that one works even without specifying the width.

Comment: @mstrkrft - You are of course free to choose any answer you prefer. Do be aware, though, that the other answer very much specifies two widths as well -- `0.6\textwidth` and `0.2\textwidth`, respectively. The ratio of these two widths is 3:1, which is quite different from what you gave in your original example, viz., 4:3.

Comment: @Mico - I know. But the code above works even without specifying the widths, which is nice :)