# Using \width command in a \subfigure width argument with the subcaption package

Tags: subcaption

I am trying to make a subfigure using the `subcaption` package.

I have the following:

```
\begin{subfigure}{\width}
  (...)
\end{subfigure}
```

I get "undefined control sequence", "missing number", "illegal unit of measure" on the `\begin{subfigure}` line.

Is this supposed to work?  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: What I want to happen is for the width of the subfigure to be determined by its contents.

Comment: What you want with this code?

Comment: @juanuni added to the original question

Comment: `\width` is no valid dimension I think, maybe you can try with `0.5\linewidht` instead `\width`

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `\subcaptionbox`, which is described in the manual for `subcaption`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232973/placing-of-subfigures-with-different-widths

Comment: `\width` is listed as an option for `minipage` which is supposed to have the same syntax as `subfigure`.  `\linewidth` does not do what I want.

Comment: @egreg `\subcaptionbox` works, why don't you make it an answer?

Comment: Maybe this can be closed as duplicate. What do you think? I believe that the linked question is pretty much the same as this.

Comment: @egreg well my specific question isn't a duplicate, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The `subcaption` package provides `\subcaptionbox` that seems exactly what you need:

```
\subcaptionbox{<caption text>\label{<label}}{%
  <image or whatever is the subfloat contents>%
}
```

Note that the caption width will be adapted to that of the contents of the subfloat, so this could lead to captions of unequal size. Whether choosing this depends on the actual contents.

The baseline for the box will be placed between the contents and the caption (which will respect the positioning decided with `\captionsetup` for subfigures or subtables), so the subfloats will be vertically aligned if they are on the same line.

There are optional arguments to `\subcaptionbox` for adapting it to other needs, check section 4 in the manual for `subcaption`.